# Django CBV's: Custom mixin's that override the same method of one View

Tags: django, inheritance, django-views, mixins

I have the following CBV with custom mixins, `AjaxFormMixin_Home` and `AjaxFormMixin_Production`.

```
# app1/views.py
class BaseView(AjaxFormMixin_Home, AjaxFormMixin_Production, FormMixin, View):
```

Based on certain ajax conditions, both mixins override `def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):` as required by `FormMixin`. See below,

```
# app1/mixins.py
class AjaxFormMixin_Home(ContextMixin, object):

   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super(AjaxFormMixin_Home, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
       obj = UserNote.objects.all()
       paginatedObject_Home = Paginator(obj, 5)
       page = self.request.GET.get('userNotepage')
       context.update('paginatedObject_Home':paginatedObject_Home.page(page))
       return context

# app2/mixins.py
class AjaxFormMixin_Production(ContextMixin, object):

   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super(AjaxFormMixin_Production, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
       obj = Production.objects.all()
       paginatedObject_Production = Paginator(obj, 5)
       page = self.request.GET.get('productionPage')
       context.update('paginatedObject_Production':paginatedObject_Production.page(page))
       return context
```

**Now, this is the problem.** Changing the order of inheritance in `BaseView` **only returns** the `context` as defined by that particular mixin. I need to return both `paginatedObject_Home` and `paginatedObject_Production` to `BaseView`.

For instance,

1. Below will only return context as defined by `AjaxFormMixin_Home`

   *class BaseView(AjaxFormMixin_Home, AjaxFormMixin_Production, FormMixin, View):*
2. Whereas below will only return context as defined by `AjaxFormMixin_Production`

   *class BaseView(AjaxFormMixin_Production, AjaxFormMixin_Home, FormMixin, View):*

Lastly, I've noticed the compiler ignores the second mixin altogether (depending on order of inheritance).

How can does one get around this type of issue?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to show your code for those methods. Do they both call `super()`? Do they merge their own data with the result of calling that?

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for reaching out. As requested, https://github.com/NeelRoshania/stackoverflow

Comment: Sorry, there's far too much code there, and it's very hard to see what's going on (especially because of the Java naming conventions and all those print statements). You need to cut down your code to the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem, and post it *here* in the question.

Comment: Thanks, will do so. How can I improve the naming conventions?

Comment: See [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the standard Python style guide.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Would really appreciate it you could point out some of these conventions so we can focus on the issue.

Comment: Focusing on the issue is the point - the naming issue was an aside, not important here. The important thing is for you to post some cut-down code, in the question, that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I've made the changes. Is the problem more clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you **Daniel** for your contribution, and for also pointing out naming convensions improvements. Would appreciate if you let me know how the code deviated from best practice as I am self taught.

Thank you **Alasdair** for pointing out the issue with Form submission and validation.

I solved the problem not by changing super call to `get_context_data`, but by changing the naming convention of methods within each mixin. The reason the context data was not updating correctly seems to be because,

1. `BaseView` inherits both mixins. And GET calls to it were making reference to duplicate method names even with vastly different functionality.

   2. **Alasdair**, as you correctly pointed out, form validation was an issue because of same method names for each mixin.

Thanks for your time guys!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the example in your question is enough to reproduce the problem. Having looked briefly at the code, the problem could be that you [are calling](https://github.com/NeelRoshania/stackoverflow/blob/master/views_Home.py#L26) the `super().get_context_data()` instead of simply `self.get_context_data()`.

However, even if that fixes the context, I don't think your current approach is going to work. You can have multiple mixins with `get_context_data` because each mixin can update the context. I don't understand how you think that multiple `form_valid` or `form_invalid` methods are meant to work together.

I would consider posting each individual form to a different view. Then your mixins only need to override `get_context_data` method, and you can have a simple view for each form.

As an aside, I don't think your mixins need to subclass `ContextMixin`. Just inherit from `object`.

Comment: Hi Alasdair, thanks for pointing that out. It was an error when simplifying the actual code base for use here. I've corrected the reference to each context individually. Have a look.

Comment: Looking briefly at the code, the problem could be `super(BaseView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)`.

Comment: Hi Alasdair, thanks for the feedback. Will take your suggestions into considerations. You mentioned, "You can have multiple mixins with get_context_data because each mixin can update the context."

If this is the case, why is the view only updating the context as defined by one of the mixins and not both?

Comment: As I said, I think that’s because you’re calling `super().get_context_data()` in the `get()` method, so one of your mixins is skipped.